# Há como criar um repositório no GitHub com um projeto já desenvolvido?

Tags: java, eclipse, github, gui, window-builder

Meu problema consiste que tenho um projeto no GitHub e esse projeto está sendo  desenvolvido por mim e mais duas pessoas. Porém, de repente, realmente não sei o que aconteceu, o meu projeto que estava todo organizado, deixou de permitir que pudesse fazer o commit, push e pull diretamente do Eclipse. Tentei pô-lo no repositório novamente, tentei cloná-lo, mas o git disse que parte do projeto já estava no computador e só me permitiu a inclusão das classes básicas (que tb. estão no meu repositório antigo). Não sei o que fazer. Para isso, uso o Git para Windows. Porém, meus colegas vem comitando código e mesmo atualizando código não consigo ter os mesmos resultados. Por exemplo, na GUI, quando rodo o programa, obtenho resultados diferentes do que é esperado (que é o que meus colegas obtêm) como desfiguração da tela, aparece de uma forma diferente do que há  no Windows Builder.

Por isso, queria criar um novo repositório, porém que "iniciasse" com código do meu projeto, bastando aos outros cloná-lo e começar a comitar lá, pq tá muito complicado, como proceder?

[image: Como fica, screenshot do meu computador]

[image: Como deveria ficar, screenshot do computador do meu amigo]

Quando tento importar o projeto que baixei do outro repositório pelo Eclipse usando o comando import > git > projects from github > existing local  repository > nome_repositorio > vai para a parte da imagem. Não consigo completar a ação (já tinha feito o repositório). Porém aparece essa imagem.
[image]

Ele não permite fazer do projeto todo, apenas das classes básica. Quem souber me ajudar quanto a isso e melhor ainda, permanecendo no mesmo repositório, agradeço mesmo.

Comment: quando você tenta realizar o commit, o git apresenta algum erro? 
@JNMarcos

Comment: Não entendi o problema @JNMarcos, não é só criar o repositório novo  e fazer um push inicial com todo o projeto?

Comment: @WellingtonSilvaRibeiro sim. Para se fazer isso, segue-se esses passos?

Comment: @WellingtonSilvaRibeiro sim. Para se fazer isso, segue-se esses passos? 1. criar repositório no site GitHub. 2. clonar o repositório para a máquina e depois? Pois o meu projeto não apresenta as opções em team de comitar, push, pull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um novo origin no seu git. Para isso use o comando `git add origin remotenovo url-do-seu-novo-repositorio`.

Depois basta fazer um commit e um push para o novo repositório:

```
git push -u remotenovo master
```

Pronto.

Comment: Ele diz que origin não faz parte do conjunto de palavras de comando. Tem como destrinchar um pouco mais. Não sei usar por meio do Shell.

Comment: Ah cara, eu inverti o comando. Vou ajustar aqui

Comment: Na verdade é add origin